# Interrupt flag is not being set

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using a thread to capture audio input which works the first time. However, I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException which I found out is because the interrupt flag isn't being set. Any help I could get would be awesome :) Below is a fully compilable example.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public MainFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(100, 100, 618, 373);

        Sessioninprogress sip = new Sessioninprogress(this);
        sip.setVisible(true);
        setContentPane(sip);
        setLayout(null);
    }
}




import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Sessioninprogress extends JPanel {

     // path of the wav file
     File wavFile = new File("C:/userconvo.wav");

     // format of audio file
     AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

     // the line from which audio data is captured
     TargetDataLine line;   

     ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);  

 public Sessioninprogress(final MainFrame parent) {


 setBounds(100, 100, 618, 373);
 setBackground(new Color(255, 250, 250));
 setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1, true));
 setLayout(null);

     JLabel txtpnEmployeeLogin = new JLabel();
     txtpnEmployeeLogin.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
     txtpnEmployeeLogin.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
     txtpnEmployeeLogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 34));
     txtpnEmployeeLogin.setText("Session in progress");
     txtpnEmployeeLogin.setBounds(150, 123, 409, 52);
     add(txtpnEmployeeLogin);

   final JButton captB = new JButton();
   captB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
   captB.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("EditorPane.selectionBackground"));
   captB.setBounds(225, 228, 153, 52);
   captB.setText("Start");   
   captB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (captB.getText().startsWith("Start")) {
               captB.setText("Stop");              
               executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        beginCapture();                 }
                });                        
             } else {
               captB.setText("Start");
               finish();
             }             

       }
   });
   add(captB);




 }

 // * Defines an audio format
 AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
     float sampleRate = 16000;
     int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
     int channels = 2;
     boolean signed = true;
     boolean bigEndian = true;
     AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                          channels, signed, bigEndian);
     return format;
 }
 // * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
 void beginCapture() {
     try {
         AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

         // checks if system supports the data line
         if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
             System.out.println("Line not supported");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
         line.open(format);
         line.start();  
         AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

         System.out.println("Start recording...");

         // start recording
         AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

     } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

  //* Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
 void finish() {
     line.stop();
     line.close();
     System.out.println("Finished");
 }
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the working example. I fixed the issue by switching to an ExecutorService.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace for the exception

Comment: Added the console output

Comment: The exception in your stack trace is not an IllegalThreadStateException...

Comment: Sorry about that, accidentally pasted a different issue. I added the proper stack trace.

Comment: Voted to close.  The Question has been updated in such a way that it is no longer possible to tell what the original problem was.  That makes it of minimal use to other people.

Comment: How do I close the post?

Comment: If you can't see a "delete" control, then you can't.  What you should do instead is to revert the >>damage<< you did by your edit.  Alternatively ask a moderator (use the "flag" control).  If you want to, you can post your solution as an Answer ... rather than destroying the Question by dumping it in there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with:

```
if(!t.isAlive())
    t.start();
```

A thread can only be started once. From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

This is why it works the first time, but not on subsequent attempts.

Comment: Then how would I go about getting it to work on subsequent attempts?

Comment: @user2916286 you would start a new thread each time, for an elegant solution read up on [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Also, on StackOverflow you generally don't want to severely edit your question so that it's significantly different (this not only potentially decreases the value of the question/answers for future visitors but also lessens the number of people seeing your altered question). If you attempt to implement an answer and have issues it's best to comment on that answer _or_ create a **new** question.

Answer (score 1):

> Then how would I go about getting it to work on subsequent attempts?

Here are some options.

1. Create a new `Thread` each time.
2. Change the design so that the `run()` method doesn't terminate.  Instead, when it is "finished" a task, get it to (say) wait on a condition variable that tells it there is more work to do, etcetera.
3. Use an `ExecutorService` instead of a bare `Thread`.

(The last option is probably the best one ...)

Comment: I tried using an Executor service and am still getting an issue. I updated the questions that shows the new source code an stack trace.

Comment: This comment doesn't make sense.  The latest update to the question says the problem is fixed, and does not include a stacktrace at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to edit the comment to say I fixed the problem after doing some extra work with the Executor service.

Comment: I see.  Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes.  But you can always delete your comments if they no longer make sense.